# Trouble changing h1 size with media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

For some reason my h1 and h4 font-size does not change with media query. Everything else does (p, img, ul and li etc).

```
            <h1 class="text_t">
                My Name
            </h1>

            <hr>
            <div class="text_c" style="text-align:center">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12"><img src="files/2.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
                    <h1>Details</h1>
                        <ul>
                            <li><strong>Name</strong>: My name Wongsajjathiti</li>
                            <li><strong>Age</strong>: My age</li>
                            <li><strong>Education</strong>: My Edu</li>
                            <li><strong>Nationality</strong>: My nat</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is my media query:

```
    /*
 * Author: http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/hardboiled_css3_media_queries/
 */

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    h1 {font-size: 1em}
    h4 {font-size:0.7em;}
    p {font-size: 0.3em;}

}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
    h1 {font-size: 1em}
    h4 {font-size:0.7em;}
    p {font-size: 0.3em;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    h1 {font-size: 1em; }
    h4 {font-size:1em}
    p {font-size: 1em}
    .intro li {font-size: 1em;}
}
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    h1 {font-size: 2em}
    h4 {font-size:1em}
    p {font-size: 1em}
    .intro li {font-size: 1em;}

}
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1224px) {
    h1 {font-size: 2em}
    h4 {font-size:1em}
    p {font-size: 1em}
    .intro li {font-size: 1em;}

}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    h1 {font-size: 2em}
    h4 {font-size:1em}
    p {font-size: 1em}
    .intro li {font-size: 1em;}}
    .icon {margin-top: -30px;}


/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    h1 {font-size: 2em}
    h4 {font-size:1em}
    p {font-size: 1em}
    .intro li {font-size: 1em;}
    .icon {margin-top: 100px;}

/* Styles */
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 724px) and (max-width: 1260px){
    h1 {font-size:5em}
    h4 {font-size:1em}
    p {font-size: 1em}
    .intro li {font-size: 1em;}
    .icon {margin-top: 90px;}
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) {
    .icon {margin-top: 300px;}
    p {font-size: 5em;}
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles *//* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

When changing the size of my desktop browser everything else readjusts accordingly, but not all the h's. Also, for some reason, I cannot change css properties of my h1 using h1 {font-family (for example) }, but only using .text_t{font-family}.

What is going on? Please help.

Thank you

Comment: These @media queries are very specific, I dare say... too specific. They seems to be stepping on each other / that is overlapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would be better off simplifying your @media queries:

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/4s76bf8t/

```
h1 {
    font-size: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 1.3rem;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 1.9rem;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 2.2rem;
    }
}
```

### This is roughly the human translations

Hopefully this helps to show that the rules overlap many places.

- in-between 320 and 480
- in-between 321 and 480
- below 320
- below 700
- in between 768 and 1024
- in between 768 and 1224
- in between 768 1024 and only when width is longer than height
- in between 768 1024 and only when height is longer than width
- in between 724 and 1260
- at least to 1260
- at least to 1824

Comment: it is doesn't work. Thank you though I am cleaning up my media queries now

Comment: If my code works perfectly on JSfiddle but not on my local host, what do you think the problem is?

Comment: Is the order different - (the order of the CSS) ? Are their any other CSS files mixed in with your code from say, bootstrap - or some other 3rd party thing?

Comment: YES! I put the bootstrap CSS after my media query. Thank you